# how to compare values between two pandas dataframes, one with list and one with single value, efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2 as follows:

```
#TWO DFs
df1 = {'uuids': [[01, 03], [02], [02,03]} 

df2 = {'uuid':[01, 02, 03]}
```

These are instances of originals. My question is how to efficiently (speedwise) print `df2` if it finds a value `01` present in `df1`?

Currently, I am doing following-

```
for j in range(len(df1)):
    for i in df1['uuids'][j]:# GOES THROUGH EACH VALUE INSIDE LIST OF COLUMN uuids
        print (df2[df2['uuid'] == i])# PRINTS df2 IF THERE IS A MATCH
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: can you share a sample dataframe, with expected output?

Comment: `df2[df2['uuid'].isin(df1['uuids'])]`

Comment: @Erfan thanks for your reply and link. Each value inside df1['uuids'] is a list type. So, how to proceed with that?

Comment: Reopened, please share a more clear example dataset. Right now you shared a dictionary and not a dataframe.

Comment: I edited the question (dataframes). Each value inside `uuids` is a list and is having variable lengths sometimes 1, 2, 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If using `pandas>=0.25`, you can use `explode` and compare the values:

```py
df2['uuid'].isin(df1.explode('uuids')['uuids'].values)

Out[1]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
```